# How do I handle permissions in my Oracle hierarchical menu query?

Tags: sql, oracle, menu, tree, hierarchical

Have a menu table:

```
create table MENU
(
   MENU_ID                        number(15,0) not null,
   PARENT_MENU_ID                 number(15,0),
   MENU_NAME                      varchar2(255 char) not null,
   PERMISSION_ID                  number(15,0)
)
/
```

And the data:

```
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (20,null,'Menu A',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (21,null,'Menu B',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (1001,null,'Menu C',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (1,1001,'Menu C-A',10);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (2,1001,'Menu C-B',34);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (3,1001,'Menu C-C',92);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (4,1001,'Menu C-D',57);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (16,1001,'Menu C-E',22);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (1002,1001,'Menu C-F',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (13,1002,'Menu C-F-A',28);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (14,1002,'Menu C-F-B',29);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (15,1002,'Menu C-F-C',43);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (1003,1001,'Menu C-G',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (5,1003,'Menu C-G-A',94);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (6,1003,'Menu C-G-B',11);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (7,1003,'Menu C-G-C',47);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (1004,1001,'Menu C-H',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (8,1004,'Menu C-H-A',120);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (9,1004,'Menu C-H-B',41);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (10,1004,'Menu C-H-C',52);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (11,1004,'Menu C-H-D',40);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (12,1004,'Menu C-H-E',39);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (2001,null,'Menu D',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (17,2001,'Menu D-A',14);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (18,2001,'Menu D-B',15);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (19,2001,'Menu D-C',106);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (3001,null,'Menu E',null);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (22,3001,'Menu E-A',16);
INSERT INTO MENU VALUES (4001,null,'Menu F',null);
COMMIT;
```

Now to return the menu structure I do:

```
select 
   level, 
   PARENT_MENU_ID,
   MENU_ID,
   SUBSTR(RPAD('-',(level-1),'-')||MENU_NAME,1,20) MENU,
   PERMISSION_ID
from
   MENU 
start with PARENT_MENU_ID is null
connect by prior MENU_ID = PARENT_MENU_ID
/
```

Giving:

```
LEVEL      PARENT_MENU_ID MENU_ID    MENU                 PERMISSION_ID 
---------- -------------- ---------- -------------------- ------------- 
         1                        20 Menu A                            
         1                        21 Menu B                            
         1                      1001 Menu C                            
         2           1001          1 -Menu C-A                       10
         2           1001          2 -Menu C-B                       34
         2           1001          3 -Menu C-C                       92
         2           1001          4 -Menu C-D                       57
         2           1001         16 -Menu C-E                       22
         2           1001       1002 -Menu C-F                         
         3           1002         13 --Menu C-F-A                    28
         3           1002         14 --Menu C-F-B                    29
         3           1002         15 --Menu C-F-C                    43
         2           1001       1003 -Menu C-G                         
         3           1003          5 --Menu C-G-A                    94
         3           1003          6 --Menu C-G-B                    11
         3           1003          7 --Menu C-G-C                    47
         2           1001       1004 -Menu C-H                         
         3           1004          8 --Menu C-H-A                   120
         3           1004          9 --Menu C-H-B                    41
         3           1004         10 --Menu C-H-C                    52
         3           1004         11 --Menu C-H-D                    40
         3           1004         12 --Menu C-H-E                    39
         1                      2001 Menu D                            
         2           2001         17 -Menu D-A                       14
         2           2001         18 -Menu D-B                       15
         2           2001         19 -Menu D-C                      106
         1                      3001 Menu E                            
         2           3001         22 -Menu E-A                       16
         1                      4001 Menu F
```

That's the simple part. Now comes in the security. Say I only want see all menu's with permission 10,11,14 and 15 then I can do:

```
select 
   level, 
   PARENT_MENU_ID,
   MENU_ID,
   SUBSTR(RPAD('-',(level-1),'-')||MENU_NAME,1,20) MENU,
   PERMISSION_ID
from
   MENU 
start with PARENT_MENU_ID is null
connect by prior MENU_ID = PARENT_MENU_ID
and PERMISSION_ID in (10,11,14,15)
/
```

Giving:

```
LEVEL      PARENT_MENU_ID MENU_ID    MENU                 PERMISSION_ID 
---------- -------------- ---------- -------------------- ------------- 
         1                        20 Menu A                            
         1                        21 Menu B                            
         1                      1001 Menu C                            
         2           1001          1 -Menu C-A                       10
         1                      2001 Menu D                            
         2           2001         17 -Menu D-A                       14
         2           2001         18 -Menu D-B                       15
         1                      3001 Menu E                            
         1                      4001 Menu F
```

But this leaves out the menu with PERMISSION_ID=11 and includes parent menus that don't have children. Ideally I want 11 included and parent menus without children excluded, specifically:

```
LEVEL      PARENT_MENU_ID MENU_ID    MENU                 PERMISSION_ID 
---------- -------------- ---------- -------------------- ------------- 
         1                      1001 Menu C                            
         2           1001          1 -Menu C-A                       10
         2           1001       1003 -Menu C-G                         
         3           1003          6 --Menu C-G-B                    11
         1                      2001 Menu D                            
         2           2001         17 -Menu D-A                       14
         2           2001         18 -Menu D-B                       15
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: `Menu A-A : 10` is a child of `Menu C` how exactly it's ended up being a child of `Menu A` in your expected output? Shouldn't  `Menu C` be present as well for `permission_id = 11`?

Comment: Thank you Nicholas Krasnov, you are correct, typo in menu names where I tried to show the structure with the names, i.e. Menu C should have been called Menu A and vice-versa - I think - will correct it when time permits (of to catch a flight now).

Comment: Corrected data, made query show the menu structure and simplified the question. Thank you Nicholas Krasnov for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You simply traverse tree from a node you are interested in (nodes with permissions 10, 11, 14 and 15 in this case) up to its root node. There is a query that does this in one of the previous editions of the question. If you are running Oracle 11g and up you can use either `connect by` or recursive common table expression:

Using `connect by`:

```
select distinct
       menu_id
     , parent_menu_id
     , menu_name
     , permission_id
  from menu m
  start with permission_id in (10, 11, 14, 15)
  connect by prior parent_menu_id = menu_id
  order by nvl(parent_menu_id, menu_id), menu_name


  MENU_ID PARENT_MENU_ID MENU_NAME            PERMISSION_ID
---------- -------------- -------------------- -------------
      1001                Menu C                            
         1           1001 Menu C-A                        10
      1003           1001 Menu C-G                          
         6           1003 Menu C-G-B                      11
      2001                Menu D                            
        17           2001 Menu D-A                        14
        18           2001 Menu D-B                        15
```

Recursive CTE:

```
with menus(menu_id, parent_menu_id, menu_name, permission_id, lv) as(
  select menu_id, parent_menu_id, menu_name, permission_id, 0
    from menu
   where permission_id in (10,11,14, 15)
   union all
   select m.menu_id, m.parent_menu_id, m.menu_name, m.permission_id, lv + 1
     from menu m
          join menus m2
            on (m.menu_id = m2.parent_menu_id)
)
select distinct 
       parent_menu_id
     , menu_id
     , menu_name
     , permission_id
  from menus 
order by nvl(parent_menu_id, menu_id), menu_name


PARENT_MENU_ID    MENU_ID MENU_NAME            PERMISSION_ID
-------------- ---------- -------------------- -------------
                     1001 Menu C                            
          1001          1 Menu C-A                        10
          1001       1003 Menu C-G                          
          1003          6 Menu C-G-B                      11
                     2001 Menu D                            
          2001         17 Menu D-A                        14
          2001         18 Menu D-B                        15
```